Why does the increment not work in two if statements?
I have written below code in C:
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

int main(){
    int n, nc, nl, nw, STATE;

    nc = nl = nw = 0;
    STATE = IN;

    while(n = getchar() != EOF){
        nc++;

        if(n == '\n'){
            nl++;
        }

        if(n == ' ' || n == '\n' || n == '\t'){
            nw++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d\n", nc, nl, nw);
}

If my input is:
"This is another\n
test\n
baby"

why does the output show
"25      0       0"

and not
"25      2       4"


while(n = getchar() != EOF) is the same as while(n = (getchar() != EOF))  ... inside the while loop n will always be either 0 (but, of course, in this case the loop isn't entered) or 1.

Using -Wall with gcc generates a warning for this.  Also for the unused variable STATE

that's the first thing they taught in the book when the getchar() function came and I forgot it. Thanks

This is not an "issue" with getchar(). The expression n = 4 != 3; does not assign 4 to n! Suggestion: (always) use (extra, redundant) parenthesis in expressions with more than 1 operator.

yeah, I should have written while((n = getchar()) != EOF) as != takes precedence over =. What I am still a little confused about is that in your first comment you say the loop is not entered but I do get value for nc which means it was entered. right ?
Also, for the first alphabet(in my case 'T') while(n = getchar() != EOF) will simplify to while(n = 0) right ?

The loop is not entered when n == 0 because 0 is false. The English is my comment is "a little" off (courtesy of 5 minute window for comment editing). For the example where the character read is 'T' what happens is the comparison 'T' != EOF which is true (or 1).

pedantic side-node: your int main() isn't returning an int. Also if you're not using argc and argv, it's considered better to use int main ( void ). It's not a huge deal, and the debate on whether or not int main() is technically correct is largely preformative. Still, it's best to be as accurate as you can while learning

@EliasVanOotegem in the absence of a return statement, main() and only main() does a implicit return 0; since C99.

@pmg: indeed. Hence my prefacing the comment with "pedantic", and ending with "it's best to be as accurate as you can while learning".

@EliasVanOotegem, oke, so I understand it's a good practice to use int main ( void ) when I am not using arguments. With your comment "your int main() isn't returning an int." This is just for my information right, nothing to correct here ?

@VinamraBali your function is defined as returning an int. You have no return statement. This only works because the standard was changed with C99 to make an exception for the main function to implicitly return 0. Personally, though, I think it's best to have the explicit return statement. Both of the things I mentioned are tiny nit-picks though

got it. thanks for explaining it :)

while(n = getchar() != EOF)
n will always be 0 or 1. != has higher precedence than = so you put the result of the comparison in n rather than storing the result of getchar() in n and comparing it to EOF.
After fixing this to while((n = getchar()) != EOF) your program appears to work correctly when I run it.
